# MOTD is updated very rarely

Tags: 13.10, pam, motd

I understand that `pam_motd` updates the MOTD upon login, but sometimes MOTD just doesn't get updated for days and I'm puzzled what might be the reason. I'd like to add `uptime` and `who` outputs to the MOTD, properly calling them from `/etc/update-motd.d/` scripts, but it seems quite pointless if users are shown outdate information.

From `update-motd` man page:

```
Executable  scripts  in  /etc/update-motd.d/* are executed by pam_motd(8) as
the root user at each login, and this information is concatenated in /var/run/motd.
The order of script execution is determined by the run-parts(8) --lsbsysinit option
(basically alphabetical order, with a few caveats).
```

In my understanding, the MOTD should be updated on each login. But it isn't. And I don't find a script which manually updates the MOTD. I could add a `run-parts` line to the `cron`, but I don't think it's the proper way to solve this issue, as it feels like a hack or workaround.

My last hope was to set `/etc/pam.d/login` like this:

```
# Prints the message of the day upon succesful login.
# (Replaces the `MOTD_FILE' option in login.defs)
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
#session    optional   pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
session    optional   pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional   pam_motd.so
```

I thought removing `noupdate` would solve the problem, but it doesn't.

Comment: Try to change last line in /etc/pam.d/login like: `session optional pam_motd.so noupdate` as suggested in [old motd is displayed on login](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/1368864)

Comment: @Letizia I already made sure that `noupdate` was only specified for the static version in `/etc/pam.d/login` and in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and not for the dynamic version.  After some more testing, I found out that creating a new script in `/etc/update-motd.d/` does not affect the MOTD until a reboot.  However, toggling the execute bit on an existing script, or moving it out of the dir and back in, does affect the MOTD without a reboot.

Comment: I got source code of update-motd, and it runs `run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d`. This could be run manually and should update motd. I got source code of `pam libraries` and I found that `pam_motd` does nothing if flag parameter's value is PAM_SILENT but unfortunately I didn't found where this parameter came from. Notice that `update-motd` is a simple shell script, but it has `-e` options, so it could be that during login session something goes wrong while during boot not. I got also `run-part` source, and I see that toggle execute bit enable/disable run-parts on this scripts.

Comment: Because of the presence of --lsbsysinit, you should check /etc/update-motd.d file's name, does those name match this options? You could run `run-parts --test --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d` that print  the  names  of  the scripts which would be run, but don't actually run them.

Comment: @Letizia I have been unable to reproduce the problem sine my last comment.  Although thanks for mentioning the `--lsbsysinit` option, as I didn't realize that doesn't allow capital letters, and am now second-guessing myself as to whether that was my problem.  If I manage to reproduce the problem I will definitely check to see if the script is included in the output of the command you mentioned.  If I can't reproduce the problem before the bounty ends, if you post an answer explaining the `--lsbsysinit` option I'll award the bounty to you.

Comment: @Letizia Also just a quick note, since this isn't my question I won't get notifications about your comments unless you include `@TheSchwa` at the beginning.

Comment: @TheSchwa thanks for bounty, but I guess you didn't reproduce the problem, so: did you change sshd_config settings? Could you check PrintMotd and UsePAM in /etc/ssh/sshd_config?

Answer (score 4):

I have recently run into the same problem.  You will need to edit `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to remove or comment out the noupdate there as well.

Comment: Can you please add more specifics on what line to look for?

Answer (score 4):

`update-motd` is a simple script that runs:

```
   run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d 2>/dev/null
```

according to [**run-parts**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/run-parts.8.html) manual:

```
   If  the  --lsbsysinit  option  is given, then the names must not end in
   .dpkg-old  or .dpkg-dist or .dpkg-new or .dpkg-tmp, and must belong  to
   one  or more of the following namespaces: the LANANA-assigned namespace
   (^[a-z0-9]+$);   the   LSB   hierarchical   and   reserved   namespaces
   (^_?([a-z0-9_.]+-)+[a-z0-9]+$);  and  the  Debian cron script namespace
   (^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$).
```

So, in order to verify if the problem is related to `update-motd` file name, try:

```
   run-parts --test --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d
```

this command prints the names of the scripts which would be run, but don't actually run them.